# The differential Linear operator of a space of polynomials of degree at most $n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've come across this statement made about the differentiation linear operator say $D$ on a vector space $V$ of polynomials of degree at most $n$. I mean the first derivative in this case.  I can verify that  indeed $V$ is a vector space and also $D$ maps the vector space V to a space of polynomials of degree at most $n-1$ which is a subspace of $V$. $D\in L(V,V)$.

My concern is with the matrix representation of this linear operator $D$. I read from a textbook that 
$$D=\left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &...     &  0 \\
   0 & 0 & 2 &0 &...  &0\\
   0 & 0 & 0& 3 &...& 0\\
   . & . &. &.&...&.\\
. & . &. &.&...&n-1\\
0 & 0 & 0& 0 &...& 0
  \end{array} } \right]
$$
 I want to know how they came about the matrix $D$. Also
considering a basis for the space $V$, $$B=\{1,x,x^2,x^3,...,x^n\}$$
What is the image of B under the operator D and how we achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the polynomials of degree at most $n$ is of dimension $n+1$, so the last column of the matrix $D$ should have entry $n$.

$D$ is in fact the matrix representation of the differentiation operator under basis $B$.

That is to say, let $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dotsc+a_nx^n$ be any polynomial, which we will represent as the vector $\vec{p}=[a_0,a_1,\dotsc,a_n]^T$.

Then the derivative of $p(x)$ is simply the vector $D\vec{p}=[a_1,2a_2,\dotsc,na_n,0]^T$, which represents $p'(x)=a_1+2a_2x+\dotsc+na_nx^{n-1}$.

Comment: Exactly. As You pointed out there seems to be a little mistake in the textbook though ($D\in\mathbb{R}^{(n+1)\times(n+1)}$)

Comment: @PeterMelech, Yes, I think I misquoted that part. thank you.